# Ancillary data : ‘IP_RECVIF’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: linux, sockets

i want to receive the ifindex of the interface on which the data is arrived. I am using the ancillary data for this purpose.
When i compile my program, i get

```
src/igmp_pkt_reciever.c:49:21: error: ‘IP_RECVIF’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

As [explained here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5173/6mbb8ae1j/index.html) , the constant should be defined in `sys/socket.h`. I have included this header file, yet i am seeing the compilation error. Can anyone please help.

Comment: That website is Solaris documentation, not Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IP_RECVIF` is not a Linux socket option; the documentation you linked to is Oracle's Solaris documentation. From [Linux socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html)

> Some other BSD sockets implementations provide `IP_RCVDSTADDR` and
>          `IP_RECVIF` socket options to get the destination address and the
>          interface of received datagrams.  Linux has the more general
>          `IP_PKTINFO` for the same task.

So you need to use `IP_PKTINFO` instead. The above web page provides the details of how to use it.